# Switching between 2 functions in C#

Tags: c#

i've 2 functions like this:

```
//Function1
public int function1()
{
...//some code
}
//function2
public double function2()
{
...//some code
}

//Main

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
function1()
function2()
}
```

in my `Main` method, how can i call `function1()` first and then `function2()`; and then sleep for *30 sec* , and again call `function1()` first and after `function2()`; and sleep for *30 sec*  and so on... ?

thanks

Comment: Is this a homework question? What is it exactly that you want to do and why?

Comment: @Zonta: what does "multithreading" tag does here, so? Do you want them execute on different threads ?

Comment: I recommend looking into System.Threading.Timer rather than dedicating a Thread that will spend most of its time sleeping.

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson what i want to do: i wrote what ; why: for fun XD

Comment: @Tigran tag removed; it was put there accidently

Comment: @Zonta I was also confused by the multithreading tag. Also if you post vague questions you're going to get vague answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a non-terminating `while` loop in combination with [`Thread.Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx).

```
while (true)
{
    function1();
    function2();
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

Naturally in a real program you would want to include some mechanism to terminate the loop.

Also, I would concur with Dan Bryant's comment above. `Sleep` is seldom the best solution to a problem and a timer would seem more appropriate here.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
while (true)
{
   function1();
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
   function2();
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what the OP wanted; I think the first sleep is unnecessary.

Comment: @AndrewBarber it's my bad, i did edited the post after he answred me, thanks both :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also implement using a System.Threading.Timer in order to get the functions to run every 30 seconds. This way you can keep the main thread active.

```
void Main()
{
    using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass())
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // Do some other stuff here (e.g. UI feedback, capture user input).
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    int _functionNumber = 1;
    bool _disposed;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(MyMethod, null, 0, 30000);
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            if (_timer != null) _timer.Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // Timer callback method
    private void MyMethod(object state)
    {
        if (_functionNumber == 1)
        {   
            function1();
            _functionNumber = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            function2();
            _functionNumber = 1;
        }
    }

    //Function1
    public int function1()
    {
        ...//some code
    }

    //function2
    public double function2()
    {
        ...//some code
    }
}
```

Comment: what is with that: `while(true){}` in the *main()* method ?

Comment: It's there to keep the main thread alive. Taking it out would result in `MyClass` being instantiated along with the `System.Threading.Timer` it uses, and then being terminated because the application terminated. I grant you that the example is contrived in order to show how you might use a Timer. You could put additional code in the `while` block, for example to listen for keyboard input from the user and terminate if the user presses 'X'.

Comment: @Zonta That's a busy loop to stop the app terminating. Don't do that!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Is having a busy loop better, the same as, or worse than using `Thread.Sleep()`? I imagine using `while(true) { };` would use more resources.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` uses no resources. A busy loop will consume an entire CPU if one is available. `System.Threading.Timer` is fine, but you do need to address the issue of what to do to keep the main thread alive.